# Two DotNetNuke (DNN) installs on the same server

Tags: dotnetnuke

How do I clone a DNN site?

The idea is to have a dev and a prod site on the same server.

I have already cloned the database and changed the connection strings.

What else needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning the site is as simple as taking a backup of the original site, and then restoring it to another location.  The backup should include the database and file system.  When restoring, be sure to introduce a new URL/Domain (known as a portal alias) for the new site to respond to.  This will need to be done in both IIS/DNS, and in DotNetNuke itself.